# C++: Visual Studio can find included header through "Go to document", but build fails

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, onnxruntime

I was attempting to restructure (filesystem-wise) a Visual Studio solution a little bit, and this solution uses an external library (specifically, Onnx Runtime; I use the NuGet OnnxRuntime Visual Studio extension Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime v1.12.0).

After restructuring, I took a look in the .vcxproj files of the various projects in my solutions, and ensured everything looked well, which it all seemed to.

When I try to build the project, however, I get this error:

`Error  C1083   Cannot open include file: 'onnxruntime_cxx_api.h': No such file or directory`

However, if I Ctrl+left click the include directive that causes this error (or alternatively: right click and choose "Go To Document"), it *does* manage to find it. The path of the opened file is: `$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsot.ML.OnnxRuntime.1.12.0\build\native\include\onnxruntime_cxx_api.h`

(Where `$(SolutionDir)` is substtuted with the actual path to my solution file.)

My solution structure is a bit strange:

```
./solution/
    ./solution.sln
    ./packages/
        ./Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.1.12.0/
            ...
    ./sources/
        ./projectA/
            projectA .cpp and .hpp files
        ./projectB/
            projectB .cpp and .hpp files
    ./vs_stuff/
        ./projectA/
            projectA Visual Studio files (vcxproj, vcxproj.users, packages.config, ...)
        ./projectB/
            projectB .cpp and .hpp files (vcxproj, vcxproj.users, packages.config, ...)
```

I looked at all of the vs_stuff files and made sure that they do indeed point to the appropriate paths, and as far as I could tell, they do.

**Potentially crucial detail:** this all started after I had attempted to restructure my solution. Initially it was the classic ./solution dir containing separate project directories, each with both sources and VS-related stuff; due to various requirements I had to change it to the structure described above, and the error resulted from this.

How might I go about solving this? The only thing I could think to do was to manually add

```
$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsot.ML.OnnxRuntime.1.12.0\build\native\include
```

to my include directories or something, but that seems excessive and ugly and wasn't necessary before; plus, the IDE *does* find the header, so I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't.

Comment: ***the IDE does find the header,  so I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't*** The compiler only looks in the same folder as your cpp source files or the system includes or the global includes or your project specific include directories. The compiler does not search all the places that the IDE does. These are independent.

Comment: @drescherjm, thanks for the input; interesting. I'd have assumed the IDE would try to ensure its behavior matches that of the compiler in that sense. Do you maybe have an idea how come the IDE could find the header file initially, even though this long path into the package wasn't directly specified in any file I could find? I struggle with finding any hint on Google...

Comment: Correction regarding my last comment: how the compiler* could find it.

Comment: I have the opposite problem, VS compiles and links fine, even IntelliSense and the Debugger work, but if I try to "Go to Document" of an include, it tells me it cannot find the file in the current source folder nor the system build paths. My .sln is generated by CMake, however, and the dependencies are installed with Conan, with the includes and libraries outside of the project folder. In the .vcxproj file, the external paths occur under `<ClCompile>`, `<ResourceCompile>`, `<Midl>`, and `<Link>`. Maybe you can check these? Do you have additional paths which make "Go to Document" work?

Answer (score 0):

The directory is added automatically by NuGet.
Please check if there  is

```
$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../../build/native/include/;
```

> I was attempting to restructure (filesystem-wise)

You may have inadvertently modified the configuration. When I moved the vcxproj file location, the line didn't exist anymore.

[image]

To fix  the problem:

1.Reinstall the  Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime package.

2. Now you may get a NuGet package error. Open the vcxproj  file with text.
   There will be multiple lines (at least 3)  like `'..\packages\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.1.12.0\build\native\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.targets`. Delete them. And  there are already right directories next  to them
   `<ImportProject="..\..\packages\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.1.12.0\build\native\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.props"`